# Matlab axis label with normal and latex

Tags: matlab

I want my `ylabel` to have the word 'Frequency' in normal/default font, but I want the 'p' to be in latex. Is this possible?

```
ylabel('Frequency ($p$)','Interpreter','latex', 'fontsize',10)
```

Comment: Do you really need 'p' to be in LaTeX, or do you just want to italicize it? If the latter, you could just use the label string `'Frequency (\it{p})'`.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski  thanks - I'd prefer if 'p' was in latex since it's a parameter in an equation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible if you define only one text element, since the `Interpreter` property applies to the whole element.

To achieve what you want, you need to use a second text element, with a different interpreter:

```
h = ylabel('Frequency ', 'Interpreter', 'tex');
text(h.Extent(1)+h.Extent(3)/2, h.Extent(2)+h.Extent(4), 'p', ...
    'Interpreter', 'Latex', 'rotation', 90);
```